# How can I delete falsy elements in an Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to delete the property `funky: false` from this object and return the other properties. Here is the code I have but for some reason it won't delete the item I need to delete.

```
var user = {
    name: "ernest",
    age: 50,
    funky: false
}

function truthyObjLoop(user) {
    for (prop in user) {
        if (prop === false) {
            delete(prop);
        } else {
            return (user);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Actual problems**

1. `delete` is a statement and not a function. So, you don't have to use `()` with that.
2. The `delete` statement removes a property from the object. When you do `delete(prop)`, it will have no effect. Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description),

   > `delete` is only **effective on an object's properties**. It **has no effect on variable or function names.**

**Solution**

So, as shown in the [syntax section of MDN's `delete` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Syntax),

> ```
> delete object.property
> delete object['property']
> ```

to delete the object's property withe the variable `prop`, you should use the second form

```
delete user[prop];
```

---

**Bugs in your code**

Apart from that, your code has two bugs.

1. You are returning immediately, if the current property's value is not `false`. You should iterate all the properties and then only you have to return.
2. You should actually check the value of `prop`, not the `prop` itself.
3. Make sure that you are declaring your loop variables. Otherwise they will become global properties.

So, your fixed code would look like this

```
function truthyObjLoop(user) {
    // Note: we use `var prop`, otherwise `prop` will become a global variable.
    for (var prop in user) {

        // This condition is to prevent removing inherited properties
        if (user.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
            continue;
        }

        if (user[prop] === false) {
            delete user[prop];
        }
    }
}

truthyObjLoop(user);

console.log(user);
// { name: 'ernest', age: 50 }
```

---

**Better way to do - avoid mutation**

Now we are changing (mutating) the current object passed. But, the better alternate would be to construct a new object, without the properties you don't want, like this

```
function truthyObjLoop(user) {
    var result = {};
    for (var prop in user) {
        if (user.hasOwnProperty(prop) === false) {
            continue;
        }
        if (user[prop] !== false) {
            result[prop] = user[prop];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(truthyObjLoop(user));
// { name: 'ernest', age: 50 }
console.log(user);
// { name: 'ernest', age: 50, funky: false }
```

Answer (score 2):

`prop` is just the name of the property. To delete it from the object you need to do:

```
delete user[prop];
```

You also need to move your `return` statement outside of the `for` loop, otherwise it will return as soon as it sees the first non-false property and not check the others.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `for-in`, the iteration variable is set to the property name, not the value (it's not like PHP `foreach`). You need to use `user[prop]` to get the value. Also, you should return after the entire loop -- you're returning as soon as you find a truthy property.

```
function truthyObjLoop(user) {
    for (prop in user) {
        if (user[prop] === false) {
            delete user[prop];
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```